# Hartshorne III 9.3 why do we need irreducibility and equidimensionality?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We are trying to prove:

Corollary 9.6: Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a flat morphism of schemes of finite type over a field $k$, and assume that $Y$ is irreducible. Then the following are equivalent:

(i) every irreducible component of $X$ has dimension equal to $\dim Y + n$;

(ii) for any point $y \in Y$ (closed or not), every irreducible component of the fibre $X_y$ has dimension $n$.

(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)
Hartshorne argues that since $Y$ is irreducible and $X$ is equidimensional and both are of finite type over $k$, we have

$$\dim_x X = \dim X - \dim \operatorname{cl}(\{x\})$$
$$\dim_y X = \dim Y - \dim \operatorname{cl}(\{y\})$$

Hartshorne makes a reference to II Ex 3.20, where one should prove several equalities for an integral scheme of finite type over a field $k$. We have that $Y$ is irreducible, so we only need it to be reduced, and then its corresponding equality will be justified. But how do we get reducedness then? And what about $X$?

Comment: sorry for the messy typing. For some reason I kept getting rendering problems even when I put the $$ signs.

Comment: Dimension is a topological property, reducedness isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I was confused by this as well.  The desired equalities follow from the general statement

> Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a field $k$ and let $x\in X$.  Then $$\dim \mathcal{O}_x+\dim \{x\}^-=\sup_{x\in V \text{ irreducible component}} \dim V$$
>
> where the sup on the right is taken over all irreducible components of $X$ containing $x$.

I posted a proof of this as an answer to my own question here: [Dimension of local rings on scheme of finite type over a field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189827/dimension-of-local-rings-on-scheme-of-finite-type-over-a-field)

The proof uses the special case from exercise II 3.20 in Hartshorne.